# Rails: Conditional subquery MAX(effective_date)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, subquery, ruby-on-rails-6.1

Let's suppose, there are three tables in the database:

**courses** (:id, :name)

**course_details** (:course_id, :effective_date, :status),

**course_codes** (:course_detail_id, :code)

*course has many course_details*

*course_detail has many cource_codes*

Course can have multiple course_details records which are effective_dated applicable (means only one record of course_detail will be used in the system).

**Problem statement:** I want to filter courses by course codes given code. And course should only be filtered by the course_codes which are linked with effective dated course_detail and should skip the past effective dated records.

```
course = Course.find(params[:id])

course_detail = CourseDetail.find_by(effective_date: CourseDetail.max(effective_date), course_id: course.id)
```

If I use this code this will filter course irrespective of effective_dated course_details:

```
Course.left_joins(course_details: :course_codes).where(course_details: { course_codes: { code: params[:code] } })
```

courses:

| Id | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | English |
| 2 | Maths |

course_details:

| id | course_id | effective_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2020-10-01 |
| 2 | 1 | 2021-01-01 |
| 3 | 2 | 2020-09-01 |

course_codes:

| id | course_detail_id | code. |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | eng-01 |
| 2 | 2 | eng-505 |
| 3 | 3 | math-01 |

when I pass *code = eng-01* it should return empty array instead of course with id 1.

Can somebody please help me?

Comment: Can you include a sample of the data and the expected result?

Comment: @max Sample data has been added.

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this issue, I used a subquery that returns ids of course_details of all the courses according to effective_date:

```
    query = "select child.id from courses as parent
  inner join course_details as child on child.course_id = parent.id
  where child.effective_date = 
  (select  max(child1.effective_date) as effective_date
  from    course_details as child1
  where   child1.course_id = parent.id
  and (child1.effective_date <= CURRENT_DATE
    or child1.effective_date = (select  min(child2.effective_date) as effective_date
    from    course_details as child2
    where   child2.course_id = parent.id)
    ))"
effective_dated_ids = Course.find_by_sql(query).pluck(:id)
```

After getting all the ids, I passed these ids in search.

```
records = Course.left_joins(course_details: :course_codes).where(course_details: { id: effective_record_ids, course_codes: { course_code: params[:course_code] } })
```

And it worked as expected.